# iterating lines with loop in java

Tags: java, while-loop

First of all I must say I read all the previous answers related to this topic and none of them were able to help me with the issue I am experiencing right now.

I created a method which reads all the lines of a file using a loop while, then stops once it finds the first line containing a specific String. What I originally want to do is to replace a line from a specific file with another line, and I tried to create the method by myself.

So here's my code so far:

```
     bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmpDirectory+"\\"+al.get(c),true));
     br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tmpDirectory+"\\"+al.get(c)));
     String textToSearch = "00";
     String textToReplace = "01";

            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line.contains(textToSearch)) {
                    bw.write(textToReplace);
                    bw.flush();
                    bw.close();
                    br.close();
                    break;
                } 
            }
```

---

The code is supposed to find a line containing the string `textToSearch` and replace it with the string `textToReplace`and when it does that, the loop stops. The issue is that the loop stops, but the file does not change.
What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I didn't see your new edit. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put that. I must add it does not throw any exception.

Comment: I tested it on my computer and it works fine. Given an input like this: `aajdfh` `ajsdf` `00`, it properly changes to this: `aajdfh` `ajsdf` `0001` (Spaces are newlines)

Comment: Yes. I found out I have an issue with the codification. Java seems to not recognise some accents from Spanish language, ex: `vualà`, java reads it as `vual�`. That's why it is not working

Comment: @Sebastian96: To fix that, use an `InputStreamReader` instead of a `FileReader`. The `FileReader` does not allow you to specify a character encoding.

Comment: As a side note, why not use `new File(dir, fileName)`? Lessens the need of using a separator.

Comment: @Sebastian96 : if there a more lines `br` and `bw` have different `Fileposition` so you are writing to the wrong line. in the example @dudeprgm you see `00` will be `0001`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said Greg, replace `FileReader` with [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) and try to give your native language as a charset in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small file and Java 7, you could use nio to read the file into lines directly

Also, if the loop stops and that is not the intention, just remove the break

```
List<String> smallFilesLines =  Files.readAllLines(tmpDirectory+"\\"+al.get(c), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);  

for (String oneLine : smallFilesLines) {
    if(oneLine.contains(textToSearch)){
        bw.write(textToReplace);
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
        break;
    }
}
```